# Show the selected value of a listview in a textview logical error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4274b148"

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have tired all the existing answer but none of them work to my needs. Basically I have a `listView` populated from my local database. I just want the show the selected value from it to the `textView`

For example:
if the user selects "Vaccine" from the `list-view`, I want "Vaccine" to appear in the `TextView`. One of the code that i've tried so far is

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        tv.setText(str);
    }
```

The above code given me `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4274b148`. but i need the actual text that store "Vaccine".

Code that populate the listview

```
private void populateListViewAppTypeFromDB() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = dbmanager.getAllAppTypeRows();

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {NewDatabaseManager.KEY_TYPEOFAPPLIANCE};
        int[] toViewIds = new int[] {R.id.appTypeNamefield};

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter 
            (
                this, 
                R.layout.item_layout_app_type,
                cursor,
                fromFieldNames,
                toViewIds
            );


        ListView myAppTypeList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.appTypeListFromDatabase);

        myAppTypeList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that puts the items into the list view.

Comment: Thank you for replying. i have updated as you requested. please check the section "Code that populates the listview"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using a `CursorAdapter`. In this case, `getItemAtPosition(position)` returns the `Cursor` at position, and you have to read the column content you want to show inside your `TextView`

eg:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

where "name" is the name of the column you want to retrieve

Comment: You rock dude !! If i owned a company, I would employ you on your desired salary. Thanks a lot :)